# KKT Conditions and Convexity

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, karush-kuhn-tucker

min  $x^2 -xy +y^2 -5x+6y$ subject to $1 \leq y$, $y^3 \leq 2x$, and $x \leq 8$

Write out the KKT conditions for this problem. Show that $(x,y) = (4,2)$ is a KKT point, and is therefore a global minimizer. Then show that $ y \to y^3 $ is convex for $y \geq 1$, show that this is a convex programming problem.

$L(x,y,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)=x^2 -xy +y^2 -5x+6y-\lambda_1(y-1)-\lambda_2(y^3-2x)-\lambda_3(x-8)$

KKT Conditions: $$\nabla _xL(x,y,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)=2x-y-5+2\lambda_2 - \lambda_3=0
$$

$$\nabla _yL(x,y,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3)= -x+2y+6-\lambda_1-3\lambda_2y^2=0$$

$$ \lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3> 0$$

$$1 \leq y, y^3 \leq 2x,x \leq 8$$

$$\lambda_1(y-1)=0$$ $$\lambda_2(y^3-2x)=0$$ $$\lambda_3(x-8)=0$$

Now to verify that $(4,2)$ is a KKT point:
All I have to do is plug in (4,2) to $\nabla _xL$ and $\nabla _yL$ to find $ \lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ but I have three unknowns and only 2 equations so how do I find the $\lambda$'s.

Any suggestions of how to show that $ y \to y^3 $ is convex for $y \geq 1$, and that this is a convex programming problem... I'm not sure how to go about this part.

Comment: Is this homework? If so it should be labeled as such.

Comment: Some comments: 1) It is not true that the $\lambda$ values are strictly positive; they may be zero. 2) You have more than 2 equations---don't forget the 3 complementary slackness equations. 3) From those, the values of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_3$ should be quite obvious, leaving only $\lambda_2$ to find.

Comment: Finally: if you cannot prove this is a convex optimization problem, why are you even *attempting* a KKT conditions problem? I genuinely don't mean to be insulting here. But proving the convexity of this model, and of $y\rightarrow y^3$ for $y\geq 1$ in particular, are among the most basic concepts that you must master if you are going to study convex optimization. You should not even be attempting to understand KKT conditions until you can do that.